# Scanner + switch use

Tags: java, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm a new to Java.

I'm currently doing a side project; making a text based game. and I realized that using Switch-statement would be very useful for this type of game.

So it is basically how it works.

I ask User, what would you like to do?

1. Eat
2. Walk
3. etc.

So, what would be the best way to build a `switch`-statement and `Scanner` together along with "default statement that asks User again"?

I've been doing this way(my code down here), but it seems it has so many potential problems.

Could you guys give me some hints on how to make a best `switch`-statement with `Scanner`?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
public static void ask() {
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        sc.next();
    }
        select = sc.nextInt();
        switch (select) {

        case 1:
            eat();
            break;
        case 2:
            walk();
            break;
        case 3:
            sleep();
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("choose from 1 to 3");
           ask();  //would you re call itself again here? or is there any otherway to do without recalling itself?

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok but I would refactor it. Also add while loop to ask again:

```
public static void ask() {

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 boolean isWrongAnswer;
 do {
    isWrongAnswer = false;
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    switch (sc.nextInt()) {
        case 1:
            eat();
            break;
        case 2:
            walk();
            break;
        case 3:
            sleep();
            break;
        default:
           System.out.println("choose from 1 to 3");
           isWrongAnswer = true;
        }
 } while (isWrongAnswer);
}
```

Comment: If I have a lot of switch-statements, is it better to have 'static Scanner sc' and share 'sc' in all switch-statements or is it better to declare it in every switch-statement individually ?

Comment: do not put scanner to static scope. Create some object, pass scanner object into it and let that object handle your input. The object can be singleton instance to be visible from multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to check first that scanner has something or not then check for whether it is int value. To do that can use sc.hasNext() & sc.hasNextInt() like below,

```
 public static void ask() {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
            while (sc.hasNext()) {
                int select = 0;
                if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                    select = sc.nextInt();
                }
                switch (select) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("call eat()");
                    break;
                case 2:

                    System.out.println("call walk()");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("call sleep()");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("choose from 1 to 3");
                    ask(); 

                }
            }
```

Comment: It depends if user can input multiple numbers to do multiple decisions at once. I think that it is not the case and hashNextInt() is pointless here.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use String in this case. To improve the readability of the code, and to avoid errors.(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

```
private static final String EAT = "1";
private static final String WALK = "2";
private static final String SLEEP = "3";

public void ask() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
    switch (sc.next()) {
        case EAT:
            eat();
            break;
        case WALK:
            walk();
            break;
        case SLEEP:
            sleep();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("choose from 1 to 3");
            ask();  // as described above via "do while", but there is nothing wrong with recursion. The garbage collector works.
    }
}
```